# How to use multiple .env files at the same time with CodeIgniter 4?

Tags: reactjs, codeigniter, environment-variables, codeigniter-4, dotenv

I use the standard `.env` file with **CodeIgniter 4**. In addition, I want to use some information from a React application that is hosted on the same server.

How can I use `/root/ci4/.env` together with `/root/react/.env` so that I can use `getenv('REACT_APP_FOO');` in my application?

The `REACT_APP_*` variable names will not exist in the `/root/ci4/.env` file, for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### STEPS:

1. Open the file `index.php` under the CodeIgniter 4 application's public path `/root/ci4/public`.
2. Load the `.env` file of the React application [just **before** the line of code `$app->run();`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/b1efbef65188ecd57cf1d2e09d769b8d11b56a0f/public/index.php#L33) in the file `/root/ci4/public/index.php`:

```php
// ...

// Load environment settings from .env file into $_SERVER and $_ENV
$envPath = ROOTPATH . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "react";
$envFileName = ".env";

if (is_file($file = $envPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $envFileName) && is_readable($file)) (new \CodeIgniter\Config\DotEnv($envPath, $envFileName))->load();

// ...
```

Where:

- `$envPath` - represents the *directory path* of the *"React application's"* `.env` file. It's assumed that it resides under `/root/react/.env`
- `$envFileName` - represents the  *"React application's"* `.env` file name.
- [`\CodeIgniter\Config\DotEnv(...)->load()`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/b1efbef65188ecd57cf1d2e09d769b8d11b56a0f/system/Config/DotEnv.php#L41) - this method is the one responsible for loading the `.env` file and processing it so that we end up with all settings in the PHP environment vars (i.e. `getenv()`, `$_ENV`, and `$_SERVER`).

##### Extra Notes:

A.

> If a `.env` variable already exists in the environment, it will
> **NOT** be overwritten.  - [Environment Variables and CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html?highlight=env#environment-variables-and-codeigniter)

This means that an environment variable defined under `/root/react/.env` **won't** overwrite a similar one defined under `/root/ci4/.env`.

B.

> *WARNING:* Note that your settings from the `.env` file are added to Environment Variables. As a side effect, this means that if your
> CodeIgniter application is (for example) generating a
> `var_dump($_ENV)` or `phpinfo()` (for debugging or other valid
> reasons) **your secure credentials are publicly exposed**.  -
> [Environment Variables and
> CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/configuration.html?highlight=env#environment-variables-and-codeigniter)

Comment: Ty! Working! Just to be extra sure: Your extra note B.... If I don't do `var_dump($_ENV)` or `phpinfo()` I'm good?

Comment: @PeterPan Yes, you should be good as long as your application **doesn't** include `var_dump($_ENV)` or `phpinfo()`.